# Qt C++ saving a image to a specified folder

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write a function that allows a user to choose an image from their local computer as a profile picture, and then save that image to a folder in my qt app folder. This is so that the app can load the profile image even when the profile picture is deleted on the user's local computer.
Below is the code snippet:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_changeprofilepic_clicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose"), "", tr("Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *bmp *.gif)"));
    if(filename == ""){
        filename = ":/images/pic/profile.png"; //If the user doesn't select a picture, set it to the default profile picture
    }
    QPixmap source(filename);
    //Some irrelevant operations on the image are deleted.
    QImage img_to_save = source.toImage(); //convert QPixmap to QImage for saving
    img_to_save.save(":/profilepic/pic/new.png"); // Here I want to save the QImage to a specified folder (A resource folder I've created for the Qt Application), but it's not working.
}
```

I have read the documentation of QImage, `bool QImage::save(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr, int quality = -1) const`, but I couldn't find how I can specify the path I save the image to. Is there anyway I can specify that path (and also print that as output)?
Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: `":/profilepic/pic/new.png"` is a resource file. You can read but not write. The `:/`  part means a binary resource that is part of the compiled program or dll. Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: ***but I couldn't find how I can specify the path I save the image to*** You prepend the path to the filename.